# Trying to build tensorflow for a Ubuntu VPS

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, ubuntu, face-api

I've been developing a Nodejs app using face-api.js that depends on @tensorflow/tfjs-node. So far everything was working well on my windows local machine and on Heroku server. But after I pushed the app to a Ubuntu VPS server the app won't run, whenever I write either

```
var tensor = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

or

```
var faceapi = require('@vladmandic/face-api');
```

The console prints "Illegal instruction" and that's it, no trace or anything. I figured maybe tensorflow is not compatible with the server system/hardware. I read that I can build tensorflow using bazel, which I tried but the server runs out of memory before the build completes. Someone told me that I can build tensorflow on my windows local machine. I tried and failed... I don't know what configurations I should use. Is there is a way to make tensorflow work on the VPS? Or successfully build one?

VPS information (I got it from NameCheap, Pulsar VPS):

- Processor information:   QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+, 2 cores
- RAM:         2 GB
- Operating system:    Ubuntu Linux 20.04
- Kernel and CPU:      Linux 5.4.0-81-generic on x86_64
- Storage:         40 GB

Comment: I faced a similar issue when I tried to install Tensorflow on a normal Ubuntu machine with a CPU. In my case, downgrading the Tensorflow version worked.

Few Links which may help: 

https://tech.amikelive.com/node-887/how-to-resolve-error-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-when-running-import-tensorflow-in-a-python-program/

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Sorry for not answering earlier, forgot about it.